# Keeping placeholder visible when typing

Tags: html, reactjs, forms, sass, placeholder

I am using React and try to build a website which allows you to analyze your twitter bubble. So, I have a form in which you can search for a twitter username. Thus, I put an "@" as a placeholder into this form, which disappears when you start typing. My goal is that the "@" stays when you start typing, so e.g. I could type "potus44" and it displays "@potus44" in this form (i hope this makes sense). So in the end, the "@" would not disappear but stay in front of the twitter handle.

See screenshot of my current form: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7CYU.png)

This is the code for my form.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import { FiTwitter } from "react-icons/fi";

const app = {
    options: []
};

const onFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const option = e.target.elements.option.value;

    if (option) {
        app.options.push(option);
        e.target.elements.option.value = '';
    }
}

class Homepage extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div className="homepage">
                <div className="container-pagecontent">
                <main style={{marginTop: '150px'}}>
                <h1 id="home" >Analyse your bubble! <FiTwitter size=".8em" /></h1>
                <p>Search for your bubble.</p>
                <form onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
                    <input placeholder="@" className ="input" type="text" name="option"/>
                    <button className="button">Suchen</button>
                </form>
                </main>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Homepage
```

And this is my scss (in case it might be useful for you).

```
.button {
    background-color: #1763A5;
    font-family: bergen;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid #1763A5;
    padding: 6px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    outline: none;
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: #1763A5;
    box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}

.input {
    width: 150px;
}

input[type=text] {
    width: 170px;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    margin: 12px 0;
    margin-right: 2px; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #1763A5;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    outline: none;
  }
```

and the code for the "container-pagecontent":

```
.container-pagecontent {
    max-width: 95rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 $m-size;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help. Let me know if you need more insights into the project.

Answer (score 1):

okay.
**In styles.scss::**

```
.homepage {
  h1::before { 
      display: block; 
      content: " "; 
      margin-top: -150px; 
      height: 130px; 
      visibility: hidden; 
      pointer-events: none;
    }
  height: 110vh;
  background-color: white; 
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

@font-face {
  src: url(/fonts/BergenText-Regular.otf);
  font-family: bergen;
}

.button {
  background-color: #1763A5;
  font-family: bergen;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid #1763A5;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
  outline: none;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: #1763A5;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}


.placeholder{
  position: relative;
}

.placeholder::after{
  content: attr(data-placeholder);
  position: absolute;
  left:0.325rem;
  top:33%;
}


input[type=text] {
  width: 170px;
  padding: 7px 0 7px 20px;
  margin: 12px 0;
  margin-right: 2px; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #1763A5;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
  outline: none;
}
```

**In App.js::**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.scss";

const app = {
  options: []
};

const onFormSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const option = e.target.elements.option.value;

  if (option) {
    app.options.push(option);
    e.target.elements.option.value = "";
  }
};

class Homepage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="homepage">
        <div className="container-pagecontent">
          <main style={{ marginTop: "150px" }}>
            <h1 id="home">Analyse your bubble!</h1>
            <p>Search for your bubble.</p>
            <form onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
              <div className="placeholder" data-placeholder="@">
                <input
                  className="input"
                  type="text"
                  name="option"
                />
              </div>
              <button className="button">Suchen</button>
            </form>
          </main>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Homepage;
```

Comment: maybe im doing this wrong as im a total beginner to coding, but when i implement it, the @ symbol is not within the form and it does not allow me to insert text at all.

Comment: okay.share your code on jsFiddle here and let me debug.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-smoke-g0zmy?file=/src/App.js Hope this helps.

Comment: It was real fun messing with react.class is called className.css is scss.haha

Comment: sorry im here now :D

Comment: okay there is one more problem, the @ is still not inside of the form. I think this is related to a container ("container-pagecontent"), I will add this code to the question, maybe you can find out why it shifts the @ to the far left side?

Comment: what!when i edited this it was totally fine.and even now,its showing fine.how can i share my sandbox?

Comment: when i use the code in sandbox, it works for me too. in my code, i have a container, which probably is responsible for this issue. Also, another problem is that when i scroll down, the form and the "@" overlap my navbar :/

Comment: i cant see any!give me your new link!

Comment: in previous link your container doesnt seem to appear.

Comment: sorry, the container is in the question, if you scroll up, you can see it

Comment: okay.but i am not seeing.i am seeing only a scrollbar.can you give me a another link that actually has a visible container?

Comment: or only the scrollbar is your container?

Comment: i try to make a new link, so you can see it. i just meant that, if you scroll up to the top of my question, you can see that i added the code for "container-pagecontent" as well, which probably is the reason why the "@" is not inside the box.